# How to make a generic 'filter' Higher-Order Component in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am making a Higher-Order Component in my React.js (+ Redux) app, to abstract the functionality to filter a list of elements with the string received from an input element.

My filtering HOC is,

**filter.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default function Filter(FilteredComponent) {
  return class FilterComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props)  {
      super(props)      
    }

    generateList() {
      if (this.props.searchTerm !== undefined)  {
        let re = new RegExp(state.searchTerm,'gi')
        return this.props.currencyList.filter((c) => c.match(re))
      }
      else {
        return this.props.currencyList
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <FilteredComponent
          filteredList={this.generateList()}
          {...this.props}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Right now, I am unable to access the filteredList as props.filteredList in the `SearchResults` component.

The component to display the list is

**SearchResults.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const SearchResults = (props) => {
  const listData = props.filteredList.map (item => <div>{item}</div>)

  return (
    <div>
      Here are the search results.
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={props.searchTerm}
        onChange={props.setSearchTerm}
      />
      {listData}
    </div>   ) }

export default SearchResults
```

How do I go on about this?

EDIT:

Adding the container component for greater clarity:

**SearchContainer.js**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import SearchResults from '../components/SearchResults'
import * as a from '../actions'
import Filter from '../enhancers/filter'

const getSearchTerm = (state) => (state.searchTerm === undefined) ? '' : state.searchTerm

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return  {
    searchTerm: getSearchTerm(state),
    currencyList: state.currencyList
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setSearchTerm: (e) => {
      dispatch(a.setSearchTerm(e.target.value))
    }
  }
}

const SearchResultsContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchResults)

export default Filter(SearchResultsContainer)
```

Comment: Doesn't look too bad to me. Is the bug maybe related to the surrounding wiring code? How did you apply the HOC? Maybe you can isolate the bug a bit further.

Comment: So what did the final solution look like? is there a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is 'state.searchTerm' in your wrapper function? I have a feeling you mean this.props.searchTerm. Also, you don't need an empty constructor in es6 classes. Also, this is work better done by a selector in your mapstatetoprops on the container.

Edit:
Also, you need to wrap the actual 'dumb' component, not the result of your connect call. That way your redux store is connected to your Filter component and will be rerendered  when you're store changes.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s first think of components as a function that takes a props and returns a Virtual DOM.

Thus the SearchResult component takes these props:

- filteredList
- searchTerm
- setSearchTerm

The higher-order-component created created by `connect()` provides these props:

- searchTerm
- currencyList

The `Filter()` higher-order component:

- takes currencyList
- provides filteredList

Therefore, you have to wire it like this so that each part receives the props it needs:

> `connect(...)` → `Filter` → `SearchResult`

It should look like this:

```
export default connect(...)(Filter(SearchResult))
```

Or if you use `recompose`:

```
const enhance = compose(connect(...), Filter)

export default enhance(SearchResult)
```

`compose()` wraps the components from right to left. Therefore, the leftmost higher-order component becomes the outermost one. This means the props will flow from left to right.

---

Please note that `state.searchTerm` in `FilterComponent#generateList` should be `this.props.searchTerm`.

Answer (score -1):

generateList() is not reactive. It does not get triggered when the search term is changed.

SearchResults should be stateful and the container component. The list component should respond to change in the search term by receiving the search term as props. generateList should be the functionality of componentWillReceiveProps of the list component.

Comment: Yeah, that is basically what I am unable to figure out.
I have provided additional information in my original post.

Comment: {...this.props} is wrong. It points to FilterComponent's props which is empty. The Filter function is not neat. It is better to write a componentWillReceiveProps in SearchResults component which will do the filtering.

Comment: searchTerm is so local to the SearchResults component that it does not make sense to put it in the Redux store. Unless there are other components dependent on searchTerm, there is no need to create an action for it.

Comment: Why is {...this.props} wrong? I suppose its passing `searchTerm` and `setSearchTerm` through to SearchResults which it is receiving.
I am not implementing the filter logic in SearchResults because I want to make it generic.
I put `searchTerm` in the store so that the higher-component can react to it.

Comment: If so, connect..(Filter(SearchResults)). Pass the HOC to connect.

Comment: If a function is used inside `render()`, then that _is_ reactive, given that the function is pure (only uses the passed arguments, `this.props` and `this.state`). It can be implemented without creating stateful components.